# Why can't I get the file name under the if statement?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am iterating over an entire directory with more than 5k .xml files and I want the file name only if it contains the string 'stop' under the tag `<name>` which itself is a child of the tag `<object>`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os
path = '/home/devf12/Documents'
listofnames = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = etree.parse(fullname)
    root = tree.getroot()
    objects = [tag for tag in root.findall('object')]
    for tag in objects:
        objname = tag.findtext('name')
        print filename # this is the last place that it will print the filename
        if objname is 'stop': # but I need to narrow it down if it meets this condition
            print filename # why wont it print here?
```

Does anyone know why my current code doesn't achieve this and how it can be done?

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare strings. It should work if you use `if objname=='stop':`.

Comment: damn it, I purposefully used is because == reported an error for some reason when I first tried it. But now it works...

Thank you! If you want you can write an answer @Rawing so i can give you award you as answered....

Comment: can you print objname and check what it contains to make sure at some point it has. If you have a space in object name then you can try if 'stop' in objename:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `is` to compare strings, use `==`:

```
if objname=='stop':
```

The differences between `is` and `==` have been discussed in detail in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python).